# How to return on client error message with status code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http

I tried to use this:

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "My message");
```

also I tried this one:

```
return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "My message");
```

But I see 500 error on my browser though any message like "My message" are displayed.

Comment: You are actually returning 500 error: `HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError` IS the 500 error.

Comment: yes, I know, but also we can return BadRequest status code and other status codes, but I still don't see the way how to send with status code my custom message, though method allows me to put my method.

Comment: Where are you returning this from? Action method in a controller?

Comment: from Action in mvc controller

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To return a specific response code with a message from ASP.NET MVC controller use:

```
return new HttpStatusCodeResult(errorCode, "Message");
```

Make sure the method in the controller is type ActionResult, not ViewResult.

Comment: this is just an exception, I want to return error with status code, it is another thing.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was under the assumption this would do what you needed. I edited the answer.

Comment: Bear in mind that this strategy won't work if you internationalise your code. For example 'return new HttpStatusCodeResult(errorCode, "未能删除用户。");' would not return what you'd expect, you'd only see '???????????'. The message text gets returned in an HTTP header, and only ASCII characters are supported (not all Unicode characters anyway).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to put a custom message in the error response body with the following code:

```
Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
Response.Clear();
Response.Write( $"Custom Error Message." );
return new HttpStatusCodeResult( HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError );
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an ErrorController that help me throwing the errors and showing a nice error page, the use `Response.StatusCode` to return a different StatusCode

```
namespace Site.Controllers {

    [OutputCache(Location = OutputCacheLocation.None)]
    public class ErrorController : ApplicationController {

        public ActionResult Index() {
            ViewBag.Title = "Error";
            ViewBag.Description = "blah blah";
            return View("Error");
        }

        public ActionResult HttpError404(string ErrorDescription) {
            Response.StatusCode = 404;
            ViewBag.Title = "Page not found (404)";
            ViewBag.Description = "blah blah";
            return View("Error");
        }


        ...

    }
}
```

**Edit** For returning message-only to ajax results I use something like this in an actionFilter

```
        Response.StatusCode = 200;

        //Needed for IIS7.0
        Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

        return new ContentResult {
            Content = "ERROR: " + Your_message,
            ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
        };
```

Comment: maybe I just use bad approach but I want to receive this message in client side with javascript.

Comment: ViewBag will not help me with it